# How to convert a tensorflow model and load as tfds

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I need help converting my dataset from how I usually make it using
`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`
To be used to replace this in an example

```
dataset, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', split=split, with_info=True,

as_supervised=True, try_gcs=True)
```

How can I do so? I am unable to find related documentation so if you can link that it would be amazing.
Thanks

This is how the dataset is used in the example

```
  split = 'train' if is_training else 'test'
  dataset, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', split=split, with_info=True,
                            as_supervised=True, try_gcs=True)


  def scale(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /= 255.0

    return image, label

  dataset = dataset.map(scale)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to register your own dataset the [TFDS Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset) seem to have what you are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to use mine dataset in place of tfds.load(). Do I really need to do all that? Is there a simpler fix?

Comment: If you just need the dataset, you can create one like in [Tensorflow Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data). If you want to register your dataset so that it's used like TFDS you will have to register it I'm afraid.

Comment: I want to use my dataset in place of such one and am unable to do so. Don't want to register. Added how it is used in example in the question